# Check if link is avaliable in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'd like to check if a link is available for clicking , 
I've tried with

```
my_link.exist?
my_link.present
```

but they both return "true" even tho the link is not clickable (grayed)

Any idea how can i check this ?

Comment: I believe the solution is dependent on how you implemented the disabling of the link. Sharing the HTML of the link would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Element#present?`](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#present?-instance_method) should do the job. It checks if the element exists and is visible on the page. You could also try [`Element#visible?`](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#visible?-instance_method)

By the way, next time please also include relevant HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the delay , Thank you .